# Doctrine 1.2 Unittesting and Code Coverage

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine, code-coverage

Is there any known way to get some kind of Code Coverage statistics in the Doctrine Unittests?

There is a directory called "Coverage" in the "tests"-dir, but I have no idea how to get that working, if possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the method. Actually it's pretty simple...

When running from the browser, add

```
?coverage=true
```

to the URL.

When running from commandline, use the

```
-coverage
```

flag